# how to adjust tab bar button in my app for iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am facing a problem while executing my app. all the tab buttons are not clearly visible means that they are shifted below with there current position. so give me some code to adjust
 the position of tab bar buttons

Thanks
 Ritesh

Comment: The buttons are below the tab bar? or the tab bar is off the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Is your tab bar loaded from the second nib file? If so, try to UNCHECK resize view from NIB